# How to parse HTML table data using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html-parsing

There's a site called NPI registry lookup which will show the information about the doctor you're searching for. Here's the URL https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/search-results-table?number=1023070703. This will list the information in table form for the doctor whose NPI number is `1023070703`, for example. What I want to do is build an angular site that will allow users to enter the NPI number, which I'd get the data using `$http.get(url)`. I received the data but it's HTML instead of just the values. How can I parse the HTML table so that I can only pick the data I need? Or is there another better way of fetching the data?

It may sound silly to create another site when there already exists one, but it's for internal purpose only which we need to save a list of doctors that are not yet in our list.

Comment: what you tried for this ?

Comment: Why don't you use their api?

Comment: I already built the site that if the user copies and pastes the data from their site, then my app will scrape the information such as name, phone number, address, etc. and saves it in the database. Which is fine, but I just thought may be if I can let them search directly from my site, then it would save them a lot of hassle. They don't have api that I can use, or at least I don't know how to get it. What I'm trying to do is the same as `importHTML` in google spreadsheet. If you read the question, I mentioned that I used `$http.get(url)` which gave me html. That's what I tried in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the sites API which is on top right.

For interactive demo:

https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/demo

1023070703 becoming something like:

https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?number=1023070703

Comment: Okay, now I'm ashamed. I did not see that at all. I must've been so focused on getting the data from what I could see that I ignored what was in front of me. Darn it!!